# Attaching a PTFE tube inside a bigger PTFE tube

Tags: adhesive, connectors

I have two PTFE tubes:

1. A thin one: OD 4mm, ID 2mm
2. A thick one: OD 6mm, ID 4mm

The thin one fits inside the thick one, and I want to glue them together so they'll have a strong connection. Glues don't work well, because it's PTFE.

I tried the following:

[image]

As you can see, I used heat-shrink tubing for the connection above. This is stronger than glue but still not strong enough, the tubes slip away if pulled hard enough.

I've seen all kinds of metal PTFE connectors online, but I can't figure out which one I should use for this specific task. Can anyone help?

Comment: What will be flowing through this?

Comment: 3d-printing filament, i.e. PLA or PETG, 1.75mm width, solid.

Comment: Does it slip so easily with your setup? I would imagine for a printer it shouldn't be under much stress. The only case I can think of is end user trying to feed in fresh filament and hitting the lip of the 4mm tubing and trying to force it.

Comment: Indeed, the 3d printer extrusion isn't causing it to slip. It slips when I manually manipulate the filament spool, dry box, or switch between filaments.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't [diy.se]. You may have more success at [3dprinting.se].

Answer (score 1):

Thread both tubes: outer thread on the small one, inner thread on the big one.

Coat small tube thread with epoxy and insert in large tube.

The glue won't stick to teflon, but it'll hang on to the threads.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a metal sleeve inside the smaller tube then use hose clamps on the outer tube which should produce sufficient compression.

The disadvantage is that these tubes slide easily, but if the pressure is not too high then it will work.

Comment: If you're putting the metal sleeve inside the thin tube, you're eating away at its ID, aren't you? The filament I'm pushing through it is a tight fit.

Comment: But the tube expands easily, so the sleeve can have the same inner diameter and with a thin wall, the tube will still easily go over it....

Comment: Yeah, I guess that could work. Where would you get a metal sleeve like that though?